# q - Applying arbitrary function while zipping

Tags: kdb, q-lang

in q the dyadic zip operation is done by `'`. I.e.

```
l1:("a1";"a2")
l2:("b1";"b2")
(l1,'l2)~("a1b1";"a2b2")
```

I parse this `'` as a dyadic operator `'[g;l2]` where `g` is a projection of some dyadic function on lists onto a monadic function, e.g. `g:,[l1;]`.

So if we want to perform any other map apart from `,` during the zipping operation, I would redefine `g`.

However, `'[g;l2]` does not give me the expected list output but returns `func`

The question is: how do I apply arbitrary maps during the zipping operation? E.g. how do I do something like `l1 f' l2` where in the example `f:,` but in general `f` some dyadic operator on to list items?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I apply arbitrary maps during the zipping operation?

Like this:

```
q)f:{x+y}
q)f'[10*x;x:til 5]
0 11 22 33 44
```

If you like the infix notation, you can also do

```
q)(10*x) f' til 5
0 11 22 33 44
```

Note that `'[g;l1]` is a [composition](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#compose).  If you want to create a projection, do

```
q)g:,'[l1;]
q)g l2
"a1b1"
"a2b2"
```